# Map Fragment OnResume function code

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, onresume, mapfragment

In Xamarin, I am modifying a class that was a standard `Activity` but is now a `Map Fragment`. The inherited `Map Fragment` is of type `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`.

Here is the previous code:

```
protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();

    // Pause the GPS - we won't have to worry about showing the 
    // location.
    _map.MyLocationEnabled = false;

    _map.InfoWindowClick -= HandleInfoWindowClick;
    _map.MarkerClick -= HandleMarkerClick;

    //_map.MarkerClick -= MapOnMarkerClick;
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    SetupMapIfNeeded();

    _map.MyLocationEnabled = true;

    _map.InfoWindowClick += HandleInfoWindowClick;
    _map.MarkerClick += HandleMarkerClick;

    // Setup a handler for when the user clicks on a marker.
    //_map.MarkerClick += MapOnMarkerClick;
}
```

This is the code I am working with:

```
protected override void Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();

    // Pause the GPS - we won't have to worry about showing the 
    // location.
    _map.MyLocationEnabled = false;

    _map.InfoWindowClick -= HandleInfoWindowClick;
    _map.MarkerClick -= HandleMarkerClick;

    //_map.MarkerClick -= MapOnMarkerClick;
}

protected override void Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    SetupMapIfNeeded();

    _map.MyLocationEnabled = true;

    _map.InfoWindowClick += HandleInfoWindowClick;
    _map.MarkerClick += HandleMarkerClick;

    // Setup a handler for when the user clicks on a marker.
    //_map.MarkerClick += MapOnMarkerClick;
}
```

I am getting errors for both of the methods. This is the error:

```
Error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
```

Can I have some help coding these functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you added `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.` to onResume and onPause methods? if you inherited your class from Fragment then no need to add this, may be that's why you have that error

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fragments and the V4 Support Library you need to:

- Install the Google Play Services (Gingerbread) or (Froyo) package
- Your fragment should then inherit from `SupportMapFragment`
- Make sure you're targeting API Level 8 in the Project Properties under the Application tab

Do not install the generic Google Play Services component, as it doesn't provide the SupportMapFragment

Then it should work.